# How Do I Make an Array of Objects a Reactive Data Source?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-helper

I have an array of objects. Say

```
var 
sidelist = [
    {
    name:"asdf", 
    id:1234,
    types:[...]


    }
];
```

Every object is turned into a box on the page using this construct

```
Template.global.side = function(){
    var obj = [], m;
    m = 1;
    for (var i in sides){
        obj.push({
            index : m,
            object : sides[i]
        });
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The HTML:

```
        {{#each side}}
            <div class="span{{this.index}}" id={{this.object.id}}>


                    <div class="side-head">{{this.object.name}}</div> 

</template>
```

There is a function that creates and pushes a new object into the array. How do I make the row of boxes reactively update on the page when the array they depend on changes?

So when I add a new object a new box should appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Dependencies, it can look like this:

```
var sidelist = ...;
var sidelist_dep = new Deps.Dependency;
```

```
Template.global.side = function(){
    sidelist_dep.depend();
    // Do your stuff here;
    return ...;
};
```

```
// Important: call this every time you change sidelist,
// AFTER the change is made.
sidelist_dep.changed();
```

See: http://docs.meteor.com/#deps

Comment: I get "undefined is not a function" when I try to do this.

Comment: When? Determine, what is undefined.

Comment: Good answer. I never took the time to look into deps and it allowed me in a practical way to get the essential. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, you should put the objects in a Meteor `Collection` instead of an array that is part of a reactive object. There are many reasons for this, including the following

- Adding, removing, searching, and updating will all be faster
- The reactivity will be on the element level instead of the array
- Meteor won't re-render the whole set of objects when something is added or deleted - just the change
- You can define a sort order on the collection, making it much more flexible than a fixed sequence

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Andrew Wilcox's isolate-value smart package:
https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/isolate-value

The README contains the exact example of selectively rerendering relevant templates when values are added/removed from an array stored in a Session varaible.